# Apply GTK theme for Python window Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: python, ubuntu, gtk

I am rather new to Python and I don't seem to find any solution of changing the GTK theme that functions on my system. I run Ubuntu 14.04 with Python 2.7.6. The following is a simplified version of the code I'm currently working on:

```
import gtk 
import webkit 

gtk.rc_parse('/home/viktor/.themes/Elegant Brit/gtk-2.0/gtkrc')

view = webkit.WebView() 

sw = gtk.ScrolledWindow() 
sw.add(view) 

win = gtk.Window(gtk.WINDOW_TOPLEVEL) 
win.add(sw) 
win.show_all() 

view.open("http://w3.org/") 
gtk.main()
```

I can't seem to find anything that works for me. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

the theme can be modified using gtkrc files stored in the following path:

```
 /usr/share/themes/[YOUR THEME]/[GTK VERSION]/gtkrc
```

use the following code to set the theme manually in your program

```
import os    
os.environ['GTK2_RC_FILES'] = '/PATH/TO/THEME/gtkrc'
```

and walla! Your window will now use the specified theme.

Tested this using wxPython 2.8.